# How to chain observables in angular, based on condition

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have a subscribe in subscribe and I would like to chain it, but I am not sure how should I continue, as intern subscribed is inside if block.

```
authenticationService.isLoggedIn$.subscribe(isLoggedIn => {
  this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    socketService.initSocket();
    authenticationService.refresh().subscribe(time => {
      this.timeOut = time.expirationTime;
      this.setTimeout(this.timeOut);
    });
  } else {
    clearTimeout(this.userActivity);
    socketService.destroySocket();
  }
});
```

I would love to chain it somehow to be able to subscribe on it only once.
I was thinking it would be good to put it inside some array which would sequentially run it?

Comment: Can you elaborate some more? I'm not sure what you are actually asking here.

Comment: I wanted to avoid having subscribe() in subscribe(), but contain the logic of code.

Answer (score 3):

A `switchMap` could do the trick. Sth along those lines:

```
return authenticationService.isLoggedIn$.pipe(
  tap(isLoggedIn => this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn),
  switchMap(isLoggedIn => isLoggedIn ? authenticationService.refresh() : of(null)))
.subscribe(time => {
  if (time) {
    this.timeOut = time.expirationTime;
    this.setTimeout(this.timeOut);
  } else {
    clearTimeout(this.userActivity);
    socketService.destroySocket();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for, I was couldn't find the tap operator :) when I was searching for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [iif](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif) operator:

```
let subscribeToFirst;
const firstOrSecond = iif(
  () => subscribeToFirst,
  of('first'),
  of('second'),
);
 
subscribeToFirst = true;
firstOrSecond.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

In case you have more than 2 options you can use manually construct if statements  in [switchMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap).

```
myObs$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(val => {
      if(a) { return obsA$ }
      else if(b) { return obsB$ }
      else { return obsElse$ }
    })
  ).subscribe();
```